Using fine tuned flux-dev model from Replicate platform locally?
I've fine tuned flux-dev model using Replicate platform. I've downloaded the weights after the training process but I do not want to generate images on web interface. Instead I want to use my local resources to generate images. Currently, I generate images locally using baseline flux-dev model.
After downloading three files captions, config.yaml and lora.safetensors where should I place them in current baseline flux-dev model dir?
